# Throws a value into another class to get value of the first row of the SQL table

Tags: c#, class

I am trying to get the first result from my SQL table row. But I get the constraint by using the class to get the result.
I want to display supplier code by entering supplier email first like this.

Class Program

```
protected void Button_register_supplier_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string email_supplier = TextBox_email_supplier.Text;

        c_supplier reg = new c_supplier();

        reg.tampil_register(email_supplier);

        Label_tampil_kode_user.Text = reg.tampil_register().ToString();
    }
```

Class Supplier

```
public string tampil_register(string email_supplier)
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();

        command.CommandText = "SELECT kode_supplier FROM tb_supplier WHERE email_supplier = @email_supplier";
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email_supplier", email_supplier);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.Connection = con;

        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
        string hasil;
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            hasil = dr.GetValue(0).ToString();
            return hasil;
        }
    }
```

So I will throw the value from my program class to supplier class to get the user code value. Then this user code will be displayed again in my program class by displaying it in my text label.

Comment: And what exactly is not working with this code?

Comment: yes, this code does not work, the problem is in `return hasil` that is in the Class Supplier and `reg.tampil_register (). ToString ();` which is in the Class Program @rene

Comment: What **exactly** is the problem?

Comment: Just do this: `Label_tampil_kode_user.Text = reg.tampil_register(email_supplier);` but you better store `hasil` in an instance variable of `Supplier` and add a property to read it.

Comment: I am also confused about what the problem is, but you do not need to `while` loop if you are going to return in the first iteration anyway. Just call `Read()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `c_supplier` class have a design flaw - you are using a class-level `SQLConnection` instance. This is a problem since it means you are not taking advantage of the built-in connection pool (and since it's implementing the  `IDisposable` interface you are risking a memory leak). You should always use a local variable for `SQLConnection`, and dispose it as soon as possible. Also, you are using `ExecuteReader` when you need to use `ExecuteScalar`, and you are not disposing your `SQLCommand` instance as well.

A better code would be something like this:

```
public string tampil_register(string email_supplier)
{
    using(var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using(var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT kode_supplier FROM tb_supplier WHERE email_supplier = @email_supplier", con))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add("@email_supplier", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = email_supplier;
            con.Open();
            var hasil = command.ExecuteScalar();
            if(hasil != null && hasil != DBNull.Value)
            {
                return hasil.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    return ""; // in case no record was found
}
```

That being said, you are also calling the `tampil_register` method twice - once with a string and once without - so your button click code should probably be:

```
protected void Button_register_supplier_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    c_supplier reg = new c_supplier();
    Label_tampil_kode_user.Text = reg.tampil_register(TextBox_email_supplier.Text);
}
```

Comment: this code works as expected and was very helpful. thank you @ZoharPeled

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)